# datatype check in sql

Tags: mysql

i want a query for this :
if a given value parses into decimal(9,4) then print the value else do nothing in SQL

Example :

```
select case when  ISNUMERIC(cast(NBR_OF_UNITS as decimal(9,4))) = 1 then 
                   cast(NBR_OF_UNITS as decimal(9,4))   
                   else 1
       end AS NBR_OF_UNITS
```

Comment: You are probably going to need to add your expected results or a use case if you want a good answer. Your query is ok when you get your expected data type, otherwise you're going to get "error converting data type varchar to numeric". I assume you are looking for a query that will evaluate to false when a string is passed instead of erroring?

Answer (score 0):

you require to do the check without cast and then if success you can do the cast as below:

```
select case when  ISNUMERIC(NBR_OF_UNITS) = 1 then 
               cast(NBR_OF_UNITS as decimal(9,4))   
               else 1
   end AS NBR_OF_UNITS
```